# How can job multi-tenancy be disabled on AWS Batch using Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

We would like to try to disable multi-tenancy for AWS batch jobs. In our Cloudformation VPC JSON we tried setting the `InstanceTenancy` to `dedicated`, but multiple jobs are still being sent to the same EC2 instance.

```
"Resources": {
    "VPC": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16",
        "InstanceTenancy": "dedicated"
      }
    },
```

Comment: I don't think the `InstanceTenancy` property has anything to do with AWS Batch. It just specifies whether you want shared or dedicated hardware. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57192073/aws-batch-to-always-launch-new-ec2-instance-for-each-job